# Re-render a function after array changes (i.e after swapping value)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to re-render a function after array values changes(i.e swap) but useeffect is not re-rendering it. Do not worry about the external components.Can you help me to this as i i want to add this code in my major project. I have attached the jsx and css file. In App.js file i am making a bar graph using the array and trying to re-render the bar() function after swapping the values.

```
import './App.css';
import "./components/Bar";
import Bar from './components/Bar';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Header from './components/Header';
import {useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {
  function bar(){
    return (
      arr.map((val, idx) => (
        <div
          className='element-bar'
          // key={idx}
          style={{
            height: `${val}px`,
            width: `${wid}px`,
            backgroundColor: "red",
            WebkitTransition: `background-color ${delay}ms linear`,
            msTransition: `background-color ${delay}ms linear`,
            transition: `background-color ${delay}ms linear`,
            transition: `${delay}ms`
          }} >
        </div>
      ))
    )
  }
  var arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1);
    bar();
  },[arr,bar]);
  function swap(x,y){
    var t = x;
    x = y;
    y = t;
  }
  function change(){
    console.log(arr);
    swap(arr[0],arr[4]);
   }
  
  const wid = 4;
  const delay = 2;
  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <button onClick={change} style={{ color: 'red' }}>Swap</button>
      <Bar/>
      <div className='array'>
        {
          bar()
        }
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
.array {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    left: 250px;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 1260px;
}

.element-bar {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sideNavbar {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 210px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(81, 81, 81,0.7);
}

.sideNavbar h3 {
    font-size: 23px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.sideNavbar h3:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sliderLabel {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.btn {
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 100px;
    color: #818181;
    font-weight: 400;
    border: 2px solid #818181;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.7), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.7);
    text-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.7), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.7);
}

.btndisabled {
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.7), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.7);
    text-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.7), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: arr is not react state, react doesn't know about it.

Comment: When you make `arr` react state, you have to create a new array and call your setState function for react to be aware of the update.

Comment: then i have to define arr as usestate hooks and in useeffect will re-render it?

Comment: Your `swap` function doesn't do anything, it simply changes the value of variables local to the function itself, but it doesn't change the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])

  const swap = (item1, item2) => {
    let cloneArray = [...arr]
    const tmp = cloneArray[item1]
    cloneArray[item1] = cloneArray[item2]
    cloneArray[item2] = tmp
    setArr(cloneArray)
  }

  const wid = 4
  const delay = 2

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => swap(0, 4)} style={{ color: 'red' }}>
        Swap
      </button>
      <div className="array">
        {arr.map((val, idx) => {
          console.log(val)
          return (
            <div
              className="element-bar"
              key={idx}
              style={{
                height: `${val}px`,
                width: `${wid}px`,
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                WebkitTransition: `background-color ${delay}ms linear`,
                msTransition: `background-color ${delay}ms linear`,
                transition: `background-color ${delay}ms linear`,
                transition: `${delay}ms`
              }}></div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't know that it should re render (i.e. call function which returns component tree again) when you mutate some array or any other data. To make React know about this, [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) should be used.
Also it better to use useCallback/useMemo to wrap all function or components which are defined in another component

```
// Put useState at the top of App() component
const [arr, setArr] = useState([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]);
const bar = useCallback(() => {
    return (
    // ...
    )
}, [])
const swap = useCallback((x,y) => {
  var t = x;
  x = y;
  y = t;
}, [])
const change = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(arr);
    const newArr = [...arr]
    swap(newArr[0],newArr[4]);
    setArr(newArr) // This string let React know that array have been changed and components should re-render
}, [])
// ...
```